# pandas: fillna with data from another dataframe, based on the same ID and keeping all values

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I want to fillna of df1, using df2, based on same colorID while keeping all rows and columns of df1.

df1=

```
colorID age  flower        
red1     12    sun
red2    na    sun
green   23    hydro
red3    na    hydro
yellow  3     sun
red4    na    hydro
```

df2=

```
colorID age
red2     4
blue     5
red3     6 
red4     7
```

desired df3 =

```
colorID age  flower        
red1     12    sun
red2     4    sun
green   23    hydro
red3     6    hydro
yellow   3     sun
red4     7    hydro
```

Tried set_index()

```
df1.set_index("colorID").age.fillna(df2.set_index("colorID").age).reset_index()
```

but only colorID and age are the outputs.

Comment: Why does "yellow" change from 3 to na while green remains at 23?

Comment: Oops! That's a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a `DataFrame` to the fillna function after setting the `index` of both the `DataFrame`s to the common field - `colorID`

```
df1 = df1.set_index('colorID')
df2 = df2.set_index('colorID')
df1 = df1.fillna(df2)
#        age flower
#colorID           
#red1     12    sun
#red2      4    sun
#green    23  hydro
#red3      6  hydro
#yellow    3    sun
#red4      7  hydro
```

Comment: Thank you Mortz, but don't I need to specify the columns with na?
df1 = df1['age'].fillna(df2['age]) 
However, only ID and age are the outputs again.

Comment: If you don't specify the columns then all columns that are common between the `df1` and `df2` will be filled in. When you do `df1=df1['age'].fillna(df2['age'])` you are changing `df1` itself by assigning it to `df1['age']` - in other words, your df1 now only contains the age column.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to specify the column that you want to use to fill the `n/a` values, keeping the rest of the Dataframe intact;

```
df_1['age'] = df_1['age'].fillna(df_2['age'])
```

Keep in mind that both Dataframes should share the same IDs to know where to look/replace the `n/a` data.

---

More examples here;

https://datascienceparichay.com/article/pandas-fillna-with-values-from-another-column/